# Nickname for Emacs users?

Tags: discussion

Is there a nickname that Emacs users use to refer to themselves or other users that heavily use Emacs and/or are proficient in Emacs? For example, Python programmers can be called "Pythonistas", which I take to be a respectful term which carries along with it the implication that the person is relatively proficient in Python. Is there an equivalent for Emacs? I have heard "Emacser" , but only once I think.

Answer (score 7):

I have seen "Emacser" used a few times, but other than that I think it's "emacs users".

Comment: agree only with "emacs users"

Comment: I tend to use Emacser: it's short and easily pronounceable.

Comment: We get enough flak for being weird on account of the software we use. Having a special name for ourselves because we use it isn't going to reduce that. "Emacs user" and its plural seem fine.

Answer (score 5):

You shall use Emacsite if you are a real believer!

[RMS's opinion](https://stallman.org/extra/church.html)

Comment: Thank you so much for this! There is so much I love about this. I would accept this as the correct answer, but even considering its origin, I don't believe there is any one right answer. This is my favorite however, and what I will call myself.

Comment: @elethan: Thank you for your kind feedback and, yes, we can become the slaves of our beliefs ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Emacsian(s) is what I use. By the way, [the plural of Emacs is Emacsen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emacs#Terminology).

Comment: Thanks! I hadn't heard that one before! I do know Emacsen, but I have never needed to use it because for me there is only one true Emacs - no need for plural, haha ;)